# Weird .net 4.0 exception when running unit tests

Tags: unit-testing, .net-4.0, moq

I am receiving the following exception when trying to run my unit tests using .net 4.0 under VS2010 with moq 3.1.

> Attempt by security transparent method
>   'SPPD.Backend.DataAccess.Test.Specs_for_Core.When_using_base.Can_create_mapper()'
>   to access security critical method
>   'Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting.Assert.IsNotNull(System.Object)'
>   failed.
>
> Assembly
>   'SPPD.Backend.DataAccess.Test,
>   Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null' is marked with
>   the
>   AllowPartiallyTrustedCallersAttribute,
>   and uses the level 2 security
>   transparency model.  Level 2
>   transparency causes all methods in
>   AllowPartiallyTrustedCallers
>   assemblies to become security
>   transparent by default, which may be
>   the cause of this exception.

The test I am running is really straight forward and looks something like the following:

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void Can_create_mapper()
    {
        this.SetupTest();

        var mockMapper = new Moq.Mock<IMapper>().Object;
        this._Resolver.Setup(x => x.Resolve<IMapper>()).Returns(mockMapper).Verifiable();

        var testBaseDa = new TestBaseDa();
        var result = testBaseDa.TestCreateMapper<IMapper>();

        Assert.IsNotNull(result);  //<<< THROWS EXCEPTION HERE 
        Assert.AreSame(mockMapper, result);

        this._Resolver.Verify();
    }
```

I have no idea what this means and I have been looking around and have found very little on the topic. The closest reference I have found is this http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/Thread/View.aspx?ThreadId=80274 but its not very clear on what they did to fix it...

Anyone got any ideas??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MSDN: *"The .NET Framework version 4 introduces new security rules that affect the behavior of the AllowPartiallyTrustedCallersAttribute  attribute (see Security-Transparent Code, Level 2). In the .NET Framework 4, all code defaults to security-transparent, that is, partially trusted. However, you can annotate individual types and members to assign them other transparency attributes."*

Haven't come across this myself, but perhaps you have imported somehing from a 3.5 project.

**Check out these links:**

[Security Changes in the .NET Framework 4](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233103.aspx)

[Security-Transparent Code, Level 2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233102.aspx)

[AllowPartiallyTrustedCallersAttribute Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.allowpartiallytrustedcallersattribute.aspx)

Comment: I don't think I imported anything from an existing project, as I created this solution/project from scratch in vs2010... The exception being thrown is on the result variable which is a dynamically created Moq object... I tried using the latest builds of Moq to see if it fixes the issues, but it didn't and as far as I know they are still building under 3.5...

Answer (score 19):

In the AssemblyInfo.cs of the referenced project add this following line

```
[assembly: System.Security.SecurityRules(System.Security.SecurityRuleSet.Level1)]
```

Answer (score 3):

This has been fixed in the latest version of Moq (it was a fix in DynamicProxy actually).
Please give the latest v4 Beta a try.

http://moq.me